# How to determine when to create an attribute and an attribute set

Tags: attributes, attribute-set

What questions do I need to ask myself for when creating attributes and attribute sets?

My physical shop sells many cake accessories and baking products, and I feel I don't comfortably know Attributes vs Attribute Sets enough in order to make a decision when creating these.

Any useful reading on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Per product think of what kind of attributes you like to show on the product view front end or layered navigation.
Now try and group these products by the attributes they share and there you have your attribute sets.

So marzipan for on the cake would probably be in the same set as some other edible sugary stuff you put on the cakes sharing attributes like color, sugar and fat contents etc etc while a cake baking form needs other attributes like the diameter.

It depends on how much information you want to give on a product. If it's minimal (color and weight) you can use 1 attribute set. If you want more detail you'll probably be better off with several sets.